# Getting an error while trying to do async network call

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am getting an error when trying to make a network call on my view. This is the error in question:

`Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '@Sendable () async throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '@Sendable () async -> Void'`

I am trying to get my code to return an array of `Result` to my view to show on the screen. How can I get rid of this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My view code:

```
struct MoviesScrollView: View {
    
    @Binding var movies: [Result]
    var movieListType: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHStack {
                    ForEach(movies, id: \.id) { movie in
                        PosterView(movie: movie)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading)
                .padding(.trailing)
            }
        }
        .task { // Line where I am getting the error.
            movies = try await NetworkManager.shared.fetchPopularMovies()
        }
    }
}
```

My network call code:

```
final class NetworkManager {
    
    static let shared = NetworkManager()
    let apiKey = "MY_API_KEY"
    
    private init() {}
    
    func fetchPopularMovies() async throws -> [Result] {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=\(apiKey)&language=en-US&page=1") else {
            print("Could not get trending movies.")
            throw AError.genericError
        }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(PopularMovieResults.self, from: data) {
                print("We got the trending movies.")
                return decodedResponse.results
            }
        } catch {
            print("Could not get trending movies.")
            throw AError.genericError
        }
        throw AError.genericError
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
movies = try await NetworkManager.shared.fetchPopularMovies()
```

To

```
do {
    movies = try await NetworkManager.shared.fetchPopularMovies()
} catch {
    // what?
}
```

Comment: As show in this answer , if you have a function that throws you must call it using a do/try/catch block.